# I’m not seeing crashes in Firebase Crashlytics in Android

Tags: firebase, crashlytics-android

```
01-05 09:41:34.872 21340 21340 I FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.2.6 for com.pandadastudio.ninjamustdie.tc
01-05 09:41:34.877 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
01-05 09:41:34.883 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics native component now available.
01-05 09:41:34.883 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: AnalyticsConnector now available.
01-05 09:41:34.888 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics listener.
01-05 09:41:34.892 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Mapping file ID is: 00000000000000000000000000000000
01-05 09:41:34.895 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Checking for cached settings...
01-05 09:41:34.896 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Loaded cached settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false,"collect_anrs":true,"collect_metric_kit":false},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"61c2d656714165c4079c913c","bundle_id":"com.pandadastudio.ninjamustdie.tc"},"expires_at":1641374928124}
01-05 09:41:34.911 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Successfully configured exception handler.
01-05 09:41:34.914 21340 21376 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
01-05 09:41:34.930 21340 21376 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 61D4F74E03900001535C2D951C7D9A5C
01-05 09:41:34.951 21340 21376 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing native session: 61D4F74E03900001535C2D951C7D9A5C
01-05 09:41:34.955 21340 21376 D FirebaseCrashlytics: No dynamic features found at /data/user/0/com.pandadastudio.ninjamustdie.tc/files/splitcompat/108/verified-splits
01-05 09:41:35.035 21340 21376 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Registered Firebase Analytics event receiver for breadcrumbs
01-05 09:41:35.957 21340 21340 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
```

This is the log i get in the adb log, and it's only in Android platform, i do not find the crash log, it's good in IOS platform. This log shows that the Crashlytics sdk is enabled,but i do not see the crash report.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/troubleshooting?platform=android

Comment: @dominicoder I have confirmed, but it did not work for me

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android

Comment: @dominicoder I have tried this page, all of the documents. And I used a test Android project, it's worked. But from the Unity, it's not work.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=unity

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, if you do not use UnityPackage for access, you need to add the following code in link.xml, you can solve this kind of problem

```xml
<linker>
<assembly fullname="Firebase.Crashlytics" ignoreIfMissing="1">
    <namespace fullname="Firebase.Crashlytics" preserve="all"/>
</assembly>
</linker>
```